# CSS: 100% height does not work for childs in WordPress with theme

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I would like to create three columns with equal height in WordPress. I am using WPBakery Builder with Minti Theme "Unicorn". Therefor I cannot post the whole code in here. But perhaps you can help me to resolve my issue.

I have tried the following (simplified, I hope, I did paste all DIVs...):

```
<body>
  <div class="site-wrapper wrapall">
    <div id="page-wrap">
      <div id="content" class="page-section nopadding">
        <div class="wpb_row vc_row-fluid standard-section section section-no-parallax space stretch">
          <div class="col span_12 color-dark left">
            <div class="vc_col-sm-12 wpb_column column_container col no-padding color-dark">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
              <div id="MYROW" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluid EQUALHEIGHT">
                <div id="MYCOLUMN1" class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4">
                  <div class="vc_column-inner">
                    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                      ...content...
                    </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
                <div id="MYCOLUMN2" class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4">
                  <div class="vc_column-inner">
                    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                      ...content...
                    </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
                <div id="MYCOLUMN3" class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4">
                  <div class="vc_column-inner">
                    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                      ...content...
                    </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

My CSS does look like this:

```
.EQUALHEIGHT .wpb_column,
.EQUALHEIGHT .vc_column-inner,
.EQUALHEIGHT .wpb_wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
```

But this does only work, if I give `#MYROW` a fixed height, then all child columns do have an equal height. 100% of it's parents.

```
#MYROW {
  height: 400px;
}
```

If I remove this fixed height of the parent, all childs have different heights.

But of course I want, the the parents height is not fixed but dynamically fit to the content of its childs.

Does anyone know, how to change that in this enviroment with WPBakery Builder and Minti Themes? Or does anyone know, how or where I can work on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the solution:

```
.EQUALHEIGHT {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: inherit;
}

.EQUALHEIGHT .vc_column_container,
.EQUALHEIGHT .vc_column-inner,
.EQUALHEIGHT .wpb_wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: inherit;
}
```

That did the trick!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).